# Run shell commands from a menu bar item

Tags: swift, macos, shell

I followed a very helpful [guide](https://www.raywenderlich.com/165853/menus-popovers-menu-bar-apps-macos) to create a simple Menu Bar app which has two actions. However, I would like 2 shell commands to be carried out when one of these actions is selected.

The current function in Xcode is:

```
func constructMenu() {
let menu = NSMenu()

menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "ON", action: #selector(AppDelegate.printQuote(_:)), keyEquivalent: "S"))
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "OFF", action: #selector(AppDelegate.printQuote(_:)), keyEquivalent: "R"))
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit SMAC", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q"))

statusItem.menu = menu
```

This shows three options as predicted when I click the menu bar:

[Screenshot of the menu bar options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2quO.png)

However, this is where my Cocoa knowledge proves insufficient. I would like the following shell scripts to be carried out when I click the ON action:

```
chmod u+x ~/Desktop/Mask.sh
~/Desktop/Mask.sh
```

And finally to carry out the following two bash scripts when the OFF button is pressed:

```
chmod u+x ~/Desktop/Unmask.sh
~/Desktop/Unmask.sh
```

Comment: You should have a look at [BitBar](https://getbitbar.com).

Answer (score 1):

The following two classes should be relevant: [`Process`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process#topics) and [`NSUserUnixTask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserunixtask).

> **Process**
>   *An object representing a subprocess of the current process.*
> <sub>Using the Process class, your program can run another program as
>   a subprocess and can monitor that program’s execution. A Process
>   object creates a separate executable entity; it differs from Thread in
>   that it does not share memory space with the process that creates
>   it.</sub>

This would be what you would use to `chmod` your script for example.

↳ [Foundation | Streams, Sockets, and Ports | Process](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process#topics)

> **NSUserUnixTask**
>   *An object that executes unix applications.*
>  <sub>The NSUserUnixTask class is intended to run unix applications, typically a
>   shell script, from your application. It is intended to execute
>   user-supplied scripts, and will execute them outside of the
>   application's sandbox, if any.</sub>

This is what could be used to execute your `shell` script.

↳ [Foundation | Processes and Threads | NSUserUnixTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserunixtask)